# Divide an array into Three parts (Recursion)

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion, dynamic-programming, partition

Problem Link:

https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/divide-to-three-33/description/

I was able to solve it using dynamic programming.
https://www.hackerearth.com/submission/1720148/

Can someone explain me the editorial solution (recursion).

Editorial Solution:

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstdio>
#include<queue>
#include<cstring>
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
#include<fstream>
#include<sstream>
using namespace std;
typedef long long int int64;
int64 n,a[40],ans,vl;
void fn(int64 i,int64 j,int64 k,int64 ptr){
    if(ptr==n){
        vl = max(max(i,j),k);if(vl<ans)ans=vl;
    }
    else{
        fn(i+a[ptr],j,k,ptr+1);
        fn(i,j+a[ptr],k,ptr+1);
        fn(i,j,k+a[ptr],ptr+1); 
    }
}
int main(){
//freopen("in3.txt","r",stdin);
//freopen("out3.txt","w",stdout);
    int64 i,j,k,l,m,t,vl,fl;ans=1000000;
    cin>>n;for(i=0;i<n;i++)cin>>a[i];
    fn(0,0,0,0);
    printf("%lld\n",ans);

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: I don't understand why -2 for this question. I had put effort in solving this question using dynamic programming. I was not able to understand the recursive solution.I wanted to understand it because it  which was very near code.

Comment: @Marco Bonelli ...have edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idea is very simple, you can add an element to anyone of the three sets(S1 or S2 or S3). Using the function `fn` the coder is doing that basically.Look for an element denoted ny `ptr` (element is `a[ptr]`) it is either added to first(`i`),second(`j`) or last(`k`). The maximum of which is given as output.

Actually all the possibilities of adding an element to any of the three sets is checked by these three lines

```
    fn(i+a[ptr],j,k,ptr+1);
    fn(i,j+a[ptr],k,ptr+1);
    fn(i,j,k+a[ptr],ptr+1);
```

The **base condition** is obviously when we finish checking all elemets in the array

```
if(ptr==n){
    vl = max(max(i,j),k);if(vl<ans)ans=vl;
    }
```

> the maximum of three set sums are found in `max(max(i,j),k)`.
>
> Now `if(vl<min)` will determine the minimum `S1` satisfying the condition. That's why this check is `v1<ans`, we will try to minimize `S1`.
>
> Here i,j,k are denoting the sum of the corresponding set.